# How can I remove the transitions from the Reveal.js slides created by Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js

When I create Reveal.js slides using the "Download as" button in Jupyter notebooks, how can I remove the transition animation from the slide.

According to the Reveal.js [page](https://revealjs.com/transitions/), I can remove the transitions by making these edits. But I don't know where this code that is to be edited can be found.

Answer (score 4):

The [configuration options](https://revealjs.com/config/), including the transition style, are specified in a `<script>` at the end of the HTML file:

```html
<script>
...
    function(Reveal, RevealNotes){
        // Full list of configuration options available here: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js#configuration
        Reveal.initialize({
            controls: true,
            progress: true,
            history: true,
            transition: "slide",
            plugins: [RevealNotes]
        });
...
</script>
```

If you change the line above to `transition: "none"`, that will remove the animation.